# extract text inside <li> tag using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
var array1[] ;

//i want to store text inside href in a array like this
// [cat,dog,cow,hen,elephant] , how can I do that?
```

```html
<div class="ABCD"><h2 class="AB">Tags</h2>
<ul>
 <li><a href="/example">cat</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example2">dog</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example3">cow</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example4">hen</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example5">elephant</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to get cat,dog,cow,hen,elephant to array animals[] using javascript.

how can I get them to a array? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below for the requirement you are looking for

```js
let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("div.ABCD  li > a")

let allLinksarray = Array.from(allLinks).map(linkElem => linkElem.innerHTML)

console.log(allLinksarray)
```

```html
<div class="ABCD">
  <h2 class="AB">Tags</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/example">cat</a></li>
    <li><a href="/example2">dog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/example3">cow</a></li>
    <li><a href="/example4">hen</a></li>
    <li><a href="/example5">elephant</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(link => array.push(link.text));

console.log(array);
```

```html
<div class="ABCD"><h2 class="AB">Tags</h2>
<ul>
 <li><a href="/example">cat</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example2">dog</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example3">cow</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example4">hen</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example5">elephant</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```js
const lists = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
let texts = lists.map(list => list.textContent);

console.log(texts);
```

```html
<div class="ABCD"><h2 class="AB">Tags</h2>
<ul>
 <li><a href="/example">cat</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example2">dog</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example3">cow</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example4">hen</a></li>
 <li><a href="/example5">elephant</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQUERY

```
const li  = $('.ABCD').find('li > a');
const resultArray = Array.from(li).map(a => a.innerHTML)
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.ABCD a');
Array.prototype.map.call(list, function (i) {
  return i.innerText
});
```

you may refer to mdn for further information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Example

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're a beginner (sorry if I'm judging incorrectly here), here's a detailed explanation at this:
[(link)](https://jsfiddle.net/s4zq56ru/)

```
let list = document.getElementById('list').children // Add the ID 'list' to the ul element, and declare it here.
let myArray = [] // Empty array for the results to go too
for (let item in list) { // For every item in the list...
    if (list[item].children) { // Take the element with the index of 'item' from the list, and find it's children (a tag)
  myArray.push(list[item].children[0].innerHTML) // Add the innerHTML (text) to a new item on the array
  }
}

console.log(myArray) // Log the Array
```

There are plenty of other solutions here that would work too

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
//variables
const items = [...$('.ABCD').find('li > a')];
const itemsText = [];

//get the list from html and puts on array
items.map(item => itemsText.push(item.text));

//console log with the text of your list
console.log(itemsText);
```